# Weird `Uncaught TypeError: unknown type returned` while returning an stream from `Observable.fromNodeCallback`

Tags: meteor, rxjs, redux-observable

As I understand so far, epic's pattern is "actions in, actions out".

I use MeteorJS, need to follow the convention of calling Meteor methods to interact with server.

Which look like this:

```
Meteor.call("<function-name>", ...args, callback)
```

So I try to handle the async side effect with epic like this:

> `completedSubscribe` is just an action creator:
>   `const completedSubscribe = result => {type: SUCCEED, result}`

```
import { Observable } from 'rx'

const fromMeteorCall = Observable.fromNodeCallback(Meteor.call)
const subscriptionsEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(REQUEST_SUBSCRIBE)
        .mergeMap(action => {
            const call$ = fromMeteorCall('subscriptions.insert', action.email)
            return call$.map(completedSubscribe)
        })
```

Then I got Error: `Uncaught TypeError: unknown type returned`

To ensure that I actual return actions out,

I try to call subscribe :

```
call$.subscribe(
  function (x) { console.log('onNext: success!'); },
  function (e) { console.log('onError: %s', e); },
  function ()  { console.log('onCompleted'); }
);
```

Then subscribe works perfectly,

but epic still can't work and keep throwing the `Uncaught TypeError: unknown type returned`.

I think it might not be MeteorJS's method problem,
this might happened in other observable created from callback.

Maybe I misunderstood something about `redux-observable` or `rxjs`,
any opinion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're receiving is coming from the `mergeMap`, it is not receiving something that it recognizes. The issue is that you are trying to use RxJS v4, not v5, with redux-observable. So while this may be confusing, I'll try to explain what is happening:

You try to return a v4 Observable to the v5 `mergeMap`, which is why it fails. Your `action$.ofType().mergeMap()` code is from RxJS v5 because that's what redux-observables uses by default, and `mergeMap` (what `flatMap` is called in v5 but not in v4). Then you import `rx` which is the package name of v4 (v5 is currently published under `rxjs`, note the js suffix). In v5 `fromNodeCallback` was renamed `bindNodeCallback`, so this confirms again that this is v4.

To solve this, I suggest you remove v4 and instead [use v5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) entirely. However if you do in fact need to use v4, we have an adapter for redux-observable you will need to install and use [redux-observable-adapter-rxjs-v4](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable-adapter-rxjs-v4). If you use it, the `action$` observable provided to your epic will now be v4 Observable, meaning you'll need to change the `mergeMap` to `flatMap` (and there are other subtle differences between the two).